# How to create a list of graphs in python?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using the networkx in python to creat a lot of graphs,and after this I need to use the Isomorphic algorithm to process them.Is there a way to save all these graph together for later retrieval like create a list for them?

Here is an example graph:

```
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_node(0, label='H') 
G.add_node(1, label='P') 
G.add_node(2, label='H') 
G.add_edge(0, 1, weight=2) 
G.add_edge(0, 2, weight=8)
```

Comment: In what format you are creating/using your graphs? Maybe show a piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can save/load your graph with networkx save/load functions, here is an example that saves the graph in pickle format:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph() 
G.add_node(0, label='H') 
G.add_node(1, label='P') 
G.add_node(2, label='H') 
G.add_edge(0, 1, weight=2) 
G.add_edge(0, 2, weight=8) 


#  save graph
nx.write_gpickle(G, "pathToGraphPickleFile.nx")

#  load graph
G2 = nx.read_gpickle("pathToGraphPickleFile.nx")


#  display loaded graph
nx.draw(G2)
plt.show()
```

For other functions:https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html